# Getting playback progress/time for multiple AVAudioPlayerNodes

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I'm trying to build an app that plays multiple audio (wav) files at different times. These wav files could all be different lengths and start and end times. I'm wanting to get playback time progress as the audio is playing back.

From all of the different tutorials and guides I've seen, this is pretty straight forward when you're just playing one audio file, as you can just get `lastRenderTime` from that `AVAudioPlayerNode`, but in my instance, I need to be able to support 1+ clips starting and ending at different (most likely concurrent) times so I can't use one `AVAudioPlayerNode` to get the `lastRenderTime` from, so I need to get the `lastRenderTime` from a different `AVAudioNode` like the engine's default output node.

I've tried to do that but there is no clear `0` time in the `outputNode`'s `lastRenderTime`.

I've also tried setting a class/instance variable to `engine.outputNode.lastRenderTime` right before playing, and then using that as a sort of anchor point to determine how long something has been playing but there is no clear `0` time in the `outputNode`'s `lastRenderTime` so that seems to be somewhat inaccurate.

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
var playerNodes = [AVAudioPlayerNode]()

func prepare() {
    engine.attach(mixer)
    engine.connect(mixer, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)

    // Create playernode and add to playerNodes

    for node in playerNodes {
        engine.attach(node)
        engine.connect(node, to: mixer, format: nil)
    }

    try! engine.start()
}

func play() {
    for node in playerNodes {
        // schedule file/segment/buffer
        node.play(at: startTimeForNode)
    }
}
```

If I have 3 two second audio file that start one second after the previous (and play along with each other), when I pressed play, I would expect a sample or millisecond accurate time of the playback overall instead of for each audio file. I'm not sure where to get the `lastRenderTime` or how to use `AVAudioTime` in such a way that I can get an real time playback time while all the clips are playing, but not for each clip specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Timer? For example (using your nodes):

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {[unowned self] timer in
                for node in playerNodes {
                    let nodeTime = node.lastRenderTime!
                    let playerTime = node.playerTime(forNodeTime: nodeTime)!
                    let secs = Double(playerTime.sampleTime) / playerTime.sampleRate
                    print(secs)
                }
```

Here's working solution: https://gist.github.com/standinga/f79232adb15e1f867ad1637f47c61003